# Is fevd for SVAR sensitive to the size of shock?

Tags: r

I am computing fevd for a SVAR on a model with three variables. When I change the size of shock (to 1 unit or 1 std) the fevd changes and the contribution of each variables to the variation of others will be different. Does it make sense? so is fevd sensitive to the size of shock?

```
Model= cbind(x,y,z)
VAR = VAR(Mod, p =5, type = c("cons"), season = NULL, exogen = NULL, lag.max = NULL)
summary(VAR)

# For SVAR models, we use recursive identification.
amat = diag(3)
diag(amat) <- 1

amat[2,1]=NA
amat[3,1]=NA
amat[3,2]=NA

SVAR = SVAR(x = VAR, estmethod = "direct", Amat = amat, Bmat = NULL, hessian = TRUE)
print(SVAR)
summary(SVAR)

sirf1 = irf(SVAR, impulse = "x", response = c("x","y", "z"), boot = TRUE, n.ahead=50,ci=0.95)
plot(sirf1)
print(sirf1)

sirf2 = irf(SVAR, impulse = "y", response = c("x","y", "z"), boot = TRUE, n.ahead=50,ci=0.95)
plot(sirf2)
print(sirf2)

sirf3 = irf(SVAR, impulse = "z", response = c("x","y", "z"), boot = TRUE, n.ahead=50,ci=0.95)
plot(sirf3)
print(sirf3)

fevd<-fevd(SVAR,n.ahead=50)
plot(fevd)`
```